# Logstash does not ingest GeoIP data to Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, geoip

I am new to ELK and I have deployed Elastic and Kibana on K8s, I would like to monitor an standalone Nginx server which is running in a standalone Ubuntu server, I have installed the filebeat and logstash on that machine (Ubuntu server) and configured the filebeat to gather the Nginx access logs and push it to Logstash, I want to enrich the logs with GeoIP data, so that I can create map on the Kibana, below is my Filebeat and Logstash configurations, what issue I am facing is that I am not getting the GeoIP data and the GeoIP fields "geo.location" gets created but I get geo failure tags:

```
"tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
      "geoip-city-failed",
      "geoip-asn-failed"
    ]
```

checking if field is created:

```
GET /endpoints/_search
{
  "_source": ["geo.location"],
  "size": 1
}

*************

{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 160,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "endpoints",
        "_id": "99eNaYoB1eIOU-vBqNqc",
        "_score": 1,
        "_ignored": [
          "message.keyword",
          "event.original.keyword"
        ],
        "_source": {}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

getting mapping detials:

```
{
  "endpoints": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "agent": {
          "properties": {
            "ephemeral_id": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "version": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "ecs": {
          "properties": {
            "version": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "event": {
          "properties": {
            "dataset": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "module": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "original": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "timezone": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "fileset": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        },
        "host": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "input": {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "log": {
          "properties": {
            "file": {
              "properties": {
                "path": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "offset": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        },
        "log_type": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "service": {
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***filebeat.yml***

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: filestream
    enabled: true
    paths:
      - /var/log/nginx/*.log
    fields:
      log_type: nginx
    fields_under_root: true
    close_inactive: 24h
 

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

setup.kibana:
  host: "192.168.30.14:5601"
  username: "$user"
  password: "$mypassword"
```

***logstash.conf***

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
        geoip {
                default_database_type => "City"
                source => "clientip"
                target => "geo"
                tag_on_failure => ["geoip-city-failed"]
        }
        geoip {
                default_database_type => "ASN"
                source => "clientip"
                target => "geo"
                tag_on_failure => ["geoip-asn-failed"]
        }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://192.168.30.12:9200"]
    index => "endpoints"
    user => "$myuser"
    password => "$mypass"
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_authorities => "/$HOME/ca.crt"
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
  }
}
```

this is the data I am getting in ES:

```
{
  "_index": "endpoints",
  "_id": "iNfbaYoB1eIOU-vBaNs7",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
      "geoip-city-failed",
      "geoip-asn-failed"
    ],
    "@timestamp": "2023-09-06T09:38:20.908Z",
    "message": "106.202.45.121 - - [06/Sep/2023:09:38:19 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 304 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36\"",
    "agent": {
      "id": "518bc225-d4dd-4e3f-a334-b7aca04e1c43",
      "version": "8.9.1",
      "ephemeral_id": "29ae20d4-b4c7-4e7e-9491-7f9f60e5c65b",
      "type": "filebeat",
      "name": "ubuntu"
    },
    "ecs": {
      "version": "1.12.0"
    },
    "log": {
      "offset": 966163,
      "file": {
        "path": "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
      }
    },
    "@version": "1",
    "event": {
      "original": "106.202.45.121 - - [06/Sep/2023:09:38:19 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 304 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36\"",
      "timezone": "+00:00",
      "dataset": "nginx.access",
      "module": "nginx"
    },
    "host": {
      "name": "ubuntu"
    },
    "service": {
      "type": "nginx"
    },
    "input": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "fileset": {
      "name": "access"
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "agent.version.keyword": [
      "8.9.1"
    ],
    "service.type.keyword": [
      "nginx"
    ],
    "input.type.keyword": [
      "log"
    ],
    "host.name.keyword": [
      "ubuntu"
    ],
    "event.dataset.keyword": [
      "nginx.access"
    ],
    "tags.keyword": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
      "geoip-city-failed",
      "geoip-asn-failed"
    ],
    "service.type": [
      "nginx"
    ],
    "agent.type": [
      "filebeat"
    ],
    "ecs.version.keyword": [
      "1.12.0"
    ],
    "event.module": [
      "nginx"
    ],
    "@version": [
      "1"
    ],
    "agent.name": [
      "ubuntu"
    ],
    "host.name": [
      "ubuntu"
    ],
    "event.timezone": [
      "+00:00"
    ],
    "log.file.path.keyword": [
      "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
    ],
    "agent.type.keyword": [
      "filebeat"
    ],
    "agent.ephemeral_id.keyword": [
      "29ae20d4-b4c7-4e7e-9491-7f9f60e5c65b"
    ],
    "event.original": [
      "106.202.45.121 - - [06/Sep/2023:09:38:19 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 304 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36\""
    ],
    "agent.name.keyword": [
      "ubuntu"
    ],
    "agent.id.keyword": [
      "518bc225-d4dd-4e3f-a334-b7aca04e1c43"
    ],
    "fileset.name": [
      "access"
    ],
    "@version.keyword": [
      "1"
    ],
    "input.type": [
      "log"
    ],
    "log.offset": [
      966163
    ],
    "message": [
      "106.202.45.121 - - [06/Sep/2023:09:38:19 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 304 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36\""
    ],
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
      "geoip-city-failed",
      "geoip-asn-failed"
    ],
    "fileset.name.keyword": [
      "access"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2023-09-06T09:38:20.908Z"
    ],
    "agent.id": [
      "518bc225-d4dd-4e3f-a334-b7aca04e1c43"
    ],
    "ecs.version": [
      "1.12.0"
    ],
    "event.original.keyword": [
      "106.202.45.121 - - [06/Sep/2023:09:38:19 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 304 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36\""
    ],
    "log.file.path": [
      "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
    ],
    "message.keyword": [
      "106.202.45.121 - - [06/Sep/2023:09:38:19 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 304 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36\""
    ],
    "event.module.keyword": [
      "nginx"
    ],
    "agent.ephemeral_id": [
      "29ae20d4-b4c7-4e7e-9491-7f9f60e5c65b"
    ],
    "agent.version": [
      "8.9.1"
    ],
    "event.dataset": [
      "nginx.access"
    ],
    "event.timezone.keyword": [
      "+00:00"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the condition to enable the geoip filter works on a field that does not exist in your documents: `[fileset][module]`, so no event get through your geoip filter.

Moreover, once you fix that condition, `COMBINEDAPACHELOG` obviously won't parse your nginx access logs as you expect (Apache != Nginx) and as a result the `message` field that geoip will parse won't contain a valid IP address.

In summary, you need to:

1. change the condition to run through the geoip filter
2. find the right grok pattern to parse your nginx access logs: this one should do the trick: `%{IPORHOST:clientip} - %{DATA:user_name} \[%{HTTPDATE:time}\] "%{WORD:method}%{DATA:url} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}" %{NUMBER:response_code} %{NUMBER:body_sent:bytes} "%{DATA:referrer}" "%{DATA:agent}"`
3. change the source field that geoip uses to a field containing a valid IP

Mapping:

```
PUT /nginx
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "geo": {
        "properties": {
          "geo": {
            "properties": {
              "location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding in comments

Comment: thanks for the answer
I have changed the filter in logstash.conf as below, now the "geo.location" field is getting created in the index but I get geoip failure with tags: [beats_input_codec_plain_applied, geoip-city-failed, geoip-asn-failed]

logstash.conf: https://ctxt.io/2/AABQzg7mFA

Comment: You're now missing the grok filter which parses the IP address out of the message field. You have no `clientip` field that the geoip filter needs.

Comment: Can you share a document that gets indexed through the updated pipeline?

Comment: now I get grok parse failure as well.

https://ctxt.io/2/AABQKcLtEg

Comment: I've updated my answer with a grok pattern that works with your message format, make sure to backslash-escape the double quotes inside the pattern

Comment: Thanks a lot, it resolved the issue, now I am getting GeoIP related data to the ES, but I have one more issue which is the field mapping, in my logstash.conf I am using source=>clientip" and "target => geo" which creates fields like "geo.geo.country_name" which is not compatible with visualization for creating map. how can I fix the mapping issue so that fields be compatible with Kibana visualization.
https://ctxt.io/2/AABQoVj-Fw

Comment: You're missing a `geo` section, see my updated answer with the appropriate mapping